# Handling aggregate and individual data input to neural networks?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classification

Consider a scenario where I have a lot of aggregate data as well as individual data that makes up that aggregated data. For example, Rotten Tomatoes, where aggregate data would be movie tags and overall critic and audience rankings, while the individual data would be each review.

Is it possible to treat this as input to a neural network? Do I just repeat the corresponding aggregated data when feeding in each individual review to be classified? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: (My first question on this specific stack exchange site, so please go easy, and understand I'm at a hobbyist level on this subject.)